# Adding a post_system hook from inside a controller method in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, php-5.6

I have some code i want to work after the request is sent to the client and closed so i want to add a `post_system` hook to the system from inside a controller, so the `post_system` hook runs only when specific method is invoked.

does `CodeIgniter` allow that in some workaround?

My version is `3.0rc3`

Comment: What is result after checking it? Any errors? Unpredictable behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible. One approach is to setup the post_system hook as described in the documentation - `$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;`, define the hook in `application/config/hooks.php`, and write the hook class.

In the controller that will use the post_system hook define a var that will be used to decide if the hook function should actually run. Set the default value to FALSE in the constructor and set it TRUE in specific method you have in mind.

Check the value of this var in your post_system_hook function. You may want to start by checking that the controller is the one that should be hooked. Let's assume that class is 'Welcome';

```
post_system_hook_function(){
     //the type of $CI will be the name of the controller
     if(get_class($CI) !== 'welcome') {
       return false;
     }

    if(! $var_that_flags_do_the_task){
       return false
    }

    //do post system code here

}
```

Answer (score -2):

i understand that you want to check a controller like if it has permition to be in ther like logged.

you need to enable the hook in your application/config/config.php

$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;

Then you need to add this lines in your application/config/hooks.php with the code

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
                                'class'    => 'PreLogin',
                                'function' => 'auth',
                                'filename' => 'PreLogin.php',
                                'filepath' => 'hooks'
                                );
```

in your apllication/hooks/PreLogin.php

```
class PreLogin{
    public function __construct(){
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->library('session');
    }

    public function auth(){
        if( ! isset($this->CI->session->userdata('id'))){
            $this->CI->session->set_flashdata('error', 'You do not have permission to enter this url');

            redirect(base_url(), 'refresh');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no , i was talking about the post_system hook to be enabled ONLY for a specific method in a specific controller